# While loop does not stop when the statement is false

Tags: python, dictionary, while-loop

I'm trying to fill a list of dictionaries. The idea is start from some dictionaries constructed as `bestpar = {'V0': 0.01976, 'theta': 0.1330, 'omega': 0.6131, 'kappa': 0.3534, 'rho': -0.8073}` and iteratively update them using this function that create 10 new dictionaries from 1 each time it is recalled:

```
def addneighbor(optgrid):

    sample_bestpar = bestpar.copy()

    neighbor = []

    for key in sample_bestpar.keys():

        neighbor.append({k : sample_bestpar[k] if k!=key else sample_bestpar[k] + delta[key] for k in sample_bestpar})
        neighbor.append({k : sample_bestpar[k] if k!=key else sample_bestpar[k] - delta[key] for k in sample_bestpar})                

    return neighbor
```

What I want to do is putting these new dictionaries inside a list until the lenght of the list becomes 100, then stop. Obviously the function is applied firstly to the initial dictionaries, then to the new dictionaries added and so on, ultile the lenght required is reached. The code to do it is the following:

```
optgrid = [bestpar]

gp = []

gp.extend(optgrid)

while (len(gp) < 100):

    for element in optgrid:

        newneighbor = addneighbor(element)

        gp.extend(newneighbor)

        for element in newneighbor:

            newnewneighbor = addneighbor(element)

            gp.extend(newnewneighbor)
```

In this case the initial dictionaries list is made of only one (bestpar) but I wanted to adapt my loop to consider cases in which there could be more initial dictionaries. Unfortunately the while loop seems not to work because the final lenght of gp becomes 111, so the code does not stop. What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You are only testing the length of `gp` after each full pass of going through `optgrid` and `newneighbor`; presumably, the length starts below 100 in one such pass, and reaches 111 by the end.  If you want to stop as soon as it reaches 100, you need to test the length whenever you add to `gp`.

A `break` statement can be used to stop a loop.

Comment: Is there a way to stop the for loop when the while statement is false? Should I put the while condition before gp.extend()? I though that the while was considering all the block below

Comment: Not sure what "considering all the block below" means; the guard condition for the `while` loop is only checked at the start of each iteration.

Comment: Since it's the second for loop that fill too much dictionaries in, I should let the for loop stop when the while statement becomes false. This is what I meant. I don't know how to insert a break in this case

Comment: probably what I am trying to do is a do-while loop and I don't want that the above code is executed until the end, because this will fill-in too much elements in the list